# How to create a 'common package' to share common logic in convector packages?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, convector

I want to create a common package to share common login in convector chain code...this is useful has the project grows and we want to share common blocks of code, utils and other useful code to don't dry the project, or hard-code strings

but how can we do it if convector currently don't support it?

Answer (score 1):

Currently convector can't use common vanilla packages (yet), only controllers, 
to work we need to hack some stuff, like create a package that implement a controller, like a fake controller. and follow some steps

thanks to **Diego** and **Walter** of **Covalent** and a few hours

> this post belongs to a github project that have a `nest.js` server, but currently is not created, when I have the link I update this post

first we start to create a lerna package for typescript, by hand

#### Create lerna common package `@convector-rest-sample/common`

`packages/common/tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "."
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

`packages/common/package.json`

```
{
  "name": "@convector-rest-sample/common",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "dist/src/index",
  "types": "dist/src/index",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm run clean && tsc",
    "clean": "rm -rf ./dist",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "3.4.3"
  }
}
```

> Note: the paths `"main": "dist/src/index"` and `"types": "dist/src/index"` are important and must point to location of the index file, if we use a wrong path, we get errors using the package

create the index to export package files

`packages/common/src/index.ts`

```js
export * from './constants';
```

`packages/common/src/constants.ts`

```js
// convector model
const CONVECTOR_MODEL_PATH_PREFIX: string = 'io.worldsibu.examples';
const CONVECTOR_MODEL_PATH_PARTICIPANT: string = `${CONVECTOR_MODEL_PATH_PREFIX}.participant`;
const CONVECTOR_MODEL_PATH_PERSON: string = `${CONVECTOR_MODEL_PATH_PREFIX}.person`;
const CONVECTOR_MODEL_PATH_ATTRIBUTE: string = `${CONVECTOR_MODEL_PATH_PREFIX}.attribute`;
const CONVECTOR_MODEL_PATH_X509IDENTITY: string = `${CONVECTOR_MODEL_PATH_PREFIX}.x509identity`;

export const appConstants = {
  CONVECTOR_MODEL_PATH_PARTICIPANT,
  CONVECTOR_MODEL_PATH_PERSON,
  CONVECTOR_MODEL_PATH_ATTRIBUTE,
  CONVECTOR_MODEL_PATH_X509IDENTITY,
};
```

now add the common package to all packages in monorepo

```sh
# add to all packages (without scope)
$ npx lerna add @convector-rest-sample/common@0.1.0
# to prevent some problems always use same version has in local package
# clean and bootstrap
$ npx lerna clean -y && npx lerna bootstrap
```

optional can use `--scope` to add only to desired packages

```sh
# add to all packages (with scope)
$ npx lerna add @convector-rest-sample/common@0.1.0 --scope server --no-bootstrap
$ npx lerna add @convector-rest-sample/common@0.1.0 --scope participant-cc --no-bootstrap
$ npx lerna add @convector-rest-sample/common@0.1.0 --scope person-cc --no-bootstrap
# clean and bootstrap
$ npx lerna clean -y && npx lerna bootstrap --hoist
```

now test `@convector-rest-sample/common` in server, add this lines to top of `packages/server/src/app.ts`
to confirm that everything is working has expected

> Note: if don't have a server, skip this step right to **Use common package inside ChainCode** section

```js
import { appConstants as c } from '@convector-rest-sample/common';
debugger;
Logger.log(JSON.stringify(c, undefined, 2));
```

now launch server with debugger, and inspect `c` object or view log result

```sh
$ npx lerna run start:debug --scope server --stream
```

if outputs appConstants we are ready to go, and common package works has expected

#### Use common package inside ChainCode

To use common package inside chaincode, is very tricky, and I lost a few hours to get it work, thanks to Walter and Diego from WorldSibu I get it.
The problem is that currently, in convector there is no easy way to use packages, that are not controllers, for this to work we must create a fake controller in `@convector-rest-sample/common` to put it to work

first install required controller dependency in our `@convector-rest-sample/common`, this is required ut use `{ Controller, Invokable }`

```sh
# install dependency
$ npx lerna add @worldsibu/convector-core --scope @convector-rest-sample/common
```

next we must create a fake controller in `packages/common/src/common.controller.ts`

```js
import { Controller, Invokable } from '@worldsibu/convector-core';

@Controller('common')
export class CommonController {
  @Invokable()
  public async greeting() {
    return 'Hello from CommonController';
  }
}
```

don't forget to add `export * from './common.controller';` to `packages/common/src/index.ts` to export controller

```js
export * from './constants';
export * from './common.controller';
```

after that we must change `chaincode.config.json` to add the fake controller, this is a hell of a hack, we use a fake controller to force the `@convector-rest-sample/common` to be copied inside `chaincode-person` dir, without this, the `@convector-rest-sample/common` is not copied and we have a broken chain code when we try deploy it with `cc:start` or `cc:upgrade` it always show the annoying error `npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @convector-rest-sample/common@0.1.0`

first change `chaincode.config.json`

> Tip: if don't have it in project, copy `org1.person.config.json` to `chaincode.config.json` and move on....

in my case I have only the legacy files `org1.participant.config.json`, `org1.person.config.json`, `org2.participant.config.json` and `org2.person.config.json`

> this files can be deleted (Diego tip)

ok let's change `chaincode.config.json` and add another controller above `person-cc`

```
"controllers": [
  {
    "name": "participant-cc",
    "version": "file:./packages/participant-cc",
    "controller": "ParticipantController"
  },
  {
    "name": "person-cc",
    "version": "file:./packages/person-cc",
    "controller": "PersonController"
  },
  // BO : ADD THIS
  {
    "name": "@convector-rest-sample/common",
    "version": "file:./packages/common",
    "controller": "CommonController"
  }
  // EO : ADD THIS
],
```

> Note: this is another clever tricky part, the `name` is the **package name**, like the one we use in imports, `version` is the **path location** inside of our build `chaincode-person`

before build chaincode we must change our models to use the new common constants from `@convector-rest-sample/common` ex `c.CONVECTOR_MODEL_PATH_X509IDENTITY`, currently this common package only use simple constants, to keep it simple, the point is created common logic for all the packages, rest-server, front-end, packages-cc, cli-tools, etc

`packages/participant-cc/src/participant.model.ts`

```js
import { appConstants as c } from '@convector-rest-sample/common';
...
export class x509Identities extends ConvectorModel<x509Identities>{
  @ReadOnly()
  public readonly type = c.CONVECTOR_MODEL_PATH_X509IDENTITY;
  ...
export class Participant extends ConvectorModel<Participant> {
  @ReadOnly()
  public readonly type = c.CONVECTOR_MODEL_PATH_PARTICIPANT;
  ...
```

`packages/person-cc/src/person.model.ts`

```js
import { appConstants as c } from '@convector-rest-sample/common';
...
export class Attribute extends ConvectorModel<Attribute>{
  @ReadOnly()
  @Required()
  public readonly type = c.CONVECTOR_MODEL_PATH_ATTRIBUTE;
  ...
export class Person extends ConvectorModel<Person> {
  @ReadOnly()
  @Required()
  public readonly type = 'io.worldsibu.example.person';
  ...
```

now we can `cc:package` the chaincode `chaincode-person`, this will package the chaincode with our `@convector-rest-sample/common` inside it with packages `person-cc` and `participant-cc` using our `@convector-rest-sample/common` constants

```sh
# first remove chaincode (optional)
$ rm chaincode-person -r
# now manually invoke package command
$ npm run cc:package -- person org1
```

after package our chaincode is advised to check if common package is copied to `chaincode-person` folder to the right path

```sh
$ ls -la chaincode-person/packages
chaincode-person/packages/@convector-rest-sample
chaincode-person/packages/participant-cc
chaincode-person/packages/person-cc
```

another good practice is check if inside `chaincode-person` folder, in file `chaincode-person/package.json`, if our `@convector-rest-sample/common` was added to `dependencies`, in above json block we can see `cc:package` script add line `"@convector-rest-sample/common": "file:./package/@convector-rest-sample/common"`, this is created based on our changes in `chaincode.config.json` remember, when we add the fake controller

```
"dependencies": {
  "@theledger/fabric-chaincode-utils": "^4.0.1",
  "@worldsibu/convector-core": "^1.3.3",
  "@worldsibu/convector-storage-stub": "^1.3.3",
  "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
  "tslib": "^1.9.0",
  "participant-cc": "file:./packages/participant-cc",
  "person-cc": "file:./packages/person-cc",
  // BO: magic line here
  "@convector-rest-sample/common": "file:./packages/@convector-rest-sample/common"
  // EO: magic line here
},
```

done now we can deploy our chaincode with `cc:start` or `cc:upgrade`

> Tip: if is first time use `cc:start`, if not use `cc:package`

to check that everything is fine from start, we restart our hyperledger stack, and start from the beginning, **warning it destroy all data**, if don't want to destroy data don't fire `npm run env:restart` and use `cc:upgrade`, more above

```sh
# this recreate environment and destroy all data
$ npm run env:restart
$ npm run cc:start -- person
# seed ledger
$ npm run seed
# create couchdb  views
$ ./views/install.sh
# invoke person_create
$ npx hurl invoke person person_create "{ \"id\": \"1-100-103\", \"firstname\": \"Pete\", \"lastname\": \"Doe\", \"username\": \"pete\", \"password\": \"12345678\", \"email\": \"pete.doe@example.com\"}" -u admin
# invoke some stuff (wait for first invoke finish)
$ npx hurl invoke person person_getAll
```

done, everything is working has expected and we have a `@convector-rest-sample/common` package implemented.

if we check couchdb `1-100-103` person, we can check that is using type `"type": "io.worldsibu.examples.person"` that comes from our constants in our `@convector-rest-sample/common`, proving that it gets its value from `@convector-rest-sample/common`, believe me, if it won't wont find `@convector-rest-sample/common` it crash.....simple

for future changes in chaincode, upgrade it with above command

```sh
# upgrade chaincode
$ npm run cc:upgrade -- person 1.1
```

we are done........

#### Use scripts to copy other files to chaincode

another thing that I tried to hack before find the solution, is using `npm scripts` but it won't work because we need the modified `chaincode-person/package.json` with `"@convector-rest-sample/common": "file:./packages/@convector-rest-sample/common"` in the `dependencies`, but I try it......

leave it here, maybe can be useful for other kind of stuff, like copy other type of stuff

```
{
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "cc:package": "f() { npm run lerna:build; chaincode-manager --update --config ./$2.$1.config.json --output ./chaincode-$1 package; npm run copy:indexes -- $1; npm run copy:package:common -- $1; }; f",
    ...
    "copy:package:common": "f () { mkdir -p ./chaincode-$1/node_modules/@convector-rest-sample/; cp -r ./packages/common/ ./chaincode-$1/node_modules/@convector-rest-sample/; }; f"
    ...
```

> note for `npm run copy:package:common -- $1;` in `"cc:package"`, and `cp -r ./packages/common/ ./chaincode-$1/node_modules/@convector-rest-sample/; };` in `"copy:package:common"`, it works, but won't modify `chaincode-person/package.json` with lines

```
"dependencies": {
  "@theledger/fabric-chaincode-utils": "^4.0.1",
  "@worldsibu/convector-core": "^1.3.3",
  "@worldsibu/convector-storage-stub": "^1.3.3",
  "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
  "tslib": "^1.9.0",
  "participant-cc": "file:./packages/participant-cc",
  "person-cc": "file:./packages/person-cc",
  // BO: magic line here
  "@convector-rest-sample/common": "file:./packages/@convector-rest-sample/common"
  // EO: magic line here
}
```

#### Clean Up

to finish we can remove the legacy files `org1.participant.config.json org1.person.config.json org2.person.config.json org2.participant.config.json`, now we use the config file `chaincode.config.json` (thanks for the tip Diego)

```sh
# remove legacy files
rm org1.participant.config.json org1.person.config.json org2.person.config.json org2.participant.config.json
```

Note: don't forget to update `packages.json` `"cc:package"` with new `./chaincode.config.json` file

`package.json`

```
"cc:package": "f() { npm run lerna:build; chaincode-manager --update --config ./chaincode.config.json --output ./chaincode-$1 package; npm run copy:indexes -- $1; }; f",
```

to finish thanks to all the kindly people of [Covalent](https://covalentx.com/)

UPDATE: in a fresh project/clone if I try to `lerna bootstrap` I get the below error

```
$ lerna bootstrap
src/participant.controller.ts:1:35 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@convector-sample/common'.

1 import { appConstants as c } from '@convector-sample/common';
```

this is because the package require build before it's used

```sh
# build common library: this is required on fresh clones before lerna boostrap
$ npx lerna run build --scope @convector-sample/common --stream
```

now it works

```sh
$ lerna bootstrap
...
lerna success Bootstrapped 6 packages
```